# Inheriting Existing ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, activex

I am currently working with a 3rd party ActiveX Control (an editor for topographical data distributed by Cadcorp SIS). I have to do some fairly complex stuff with it in a VB.NET (framework 4) program and am finding that the API that comes with the control is quite limited.

As of now I have made a custom control which houses the control and acts as a wrapper for it to allow me to extend the API, which works fine, but What I would really like to do it give the control more events so that I can monitor what is going on with the data more closely.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this though...

I tried inheriting from the control and I can extend it just fine, but I can't figure out how to reuse it after that. Is there some way I can inherit the control and get it to appear in the toolbox so I can just drop it onto a form? Or do I have to load it programatically? If so, how can I do it?

Any pointers, examples, tutorials or alternative ideas as to how to do this kind of thing would be welcome.

Comment: You can't really add more events/properties/methods to ActiveX control without changing its code. Do you know if events you need already exposed by the control but are simply not convinient/not possible to use from CLR?

Comment: I would like to implement some custom properties on the control which would require monitoring which API commands are being executed, but the events that are exposed do not cover that part. I was hoping I could inherit and wrap the relevant API commands so that they would fire an event when called.

Comment: If you just want events around calls to the ActiveX control - why can't you do that in you VB.Net layer? Or you need ActiveX control to insert on HTML page? Or need to reuse it in some special way (more thatn simple wrapper class with all methods + events fired around method calls?

Comment: Yes, that is one solution. I thought of that, but dismissed it because I thought I could never be sure that I wouldn't get a call bypassing my wrapper, straight to the ActiveX control... But now that I think of it I think I could do that if restrict the access to the control (wide open at the moment, because that's how the app was built ten years ago). That sounds promising, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing your control class in toolbox it doesn’t mean that you can’t use it just modify code from your form's designer to use your inherited class

Or

You can drag-and-drop your assembly (dll) from Windows Explorer to the
toolbox in VS.NET. Or you can right click on the toolbox in VS.NET and
choose Add/Remove items. Is this what you are looking for?

Also

```
<ToolBoxItem(True), ToolboxBitmap("MyNamespace.MyClass.bmp")> _
    Public Class MyClass
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am trying to do.